# Haskell: type classes question

Tags: haskell, typeclass

I wish to define the following typeclass `Mapping`:

```
{-# LANGUAGE MultiParamTypeClasses #-}

class Mapping k v m where
  empty :: m v
  insert :: k -> v -> m v -> m v
  search :: k -> m v -> Maybe v
  delete :: k -> m v -> m v
```

One instance of `Mapping` is `Data.Map.Map`

```
{-# LANGUAGE ..., FlexibleInstances #-}

instance Ord k => Mapping k v (Map.Map k) where
  empty = Map.empty
  search = Map.lookup
  insert = Map.insert
  delete = Map.delete
```

And now I want to create a type `Trie :: * -> * -> * -> *` such as

```
{-# LANGUAGE ..., UndecidableInstances #-}

data Trie m k v = Trie {
  trValue :: Maybe v,
  trChildren :: m (Trie m k v)
}

instance Mapping k (Trie m k v) m => Mapping [k] v (Trie m k) where
  search [] tree = trValue tree
  search (x:xs) tree =
    search xs =<< search x (trChildren tree)
```

So far so good,
now I also want to define `Trie`'s `insert` and `empty`, and that's where I get into problems.

I will discuss `empty` because it's simpler and `insert` needs it anyhow..
If I try this:

```
instance Mapping k (Trie m k v) m => Mapping [k] v (Trie m k) where
  empty = Trie { trValue = Nothing, trChildren = empty }
  ...
```

and that makes me get the following error:

```
Could not deduce (Mapping k (Trie m k1 v) (m k1))
  from the context (Mapping [k1] v (Trie m k1),
                    Mapping k1 (Trie m k1 v) (m k1))
  arising from a use of `empty' at test.hs:27:49-53
Possible fix:
  add (Mapping k (Trie m k1 v) (m k1)) to the context of
    the instance declaration
  or add an instance declaration for (Mapping k (Trie m k1 v) (m k1))
In the `trChildren' field of a record
In the expression: Trie {trValue = Nothing, trChildren = empty}
In the definition of `empty':
    empty = Trie {trValue = Nothing, trChildren = empty}
```

I've tried and tried to solve it but failed.

Does anyone know how to make it work? Is it even possible?

Comment: BTW, I suggest removing the `v` from the type class definition (but leave it in the signatures of the methods). You don't need it, at least for all the structures you've given so far, because they will all take any contained type, and it makes everything simpler.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Add a [functional dependency](http://www.haskell.org/haskellwiki/Functional_dependencies):

```
{-# LANGUAGE ..., FunctionalDependencies #-}

class Mapping k v m | m -> k where
   ...
```

The errors you got before were because the program was ambiguous about which key type to use in certain places, hence the errors about the type variable `k1`. The functional dependency allows the key type to be deduced from the map type (by declaring that there is only one possible answer), which deals with this problem.

Comment: Thanks! I coded it (see below) and it came out quite neat thanks to your suggestion about removing v from the type class definition.

Answer (score 7):

Code to demonstrate Ganesh's answer:

```
{-# LANGUAGE FlexibleInstances, FunctionalDependencies, MultiParamTypeClasses, StandaloneDeriving, UndecidableInstances #-}

import qualified Data.Map as Map
import Data.Maybe (fromMaybe)

class Mapping k m | m -> k where             
  empty :: m v
  insert :: k -> v -> m v -> m v
  search :: k -> m v -> Maybe v
  delete :: k -> m v -> m v

instance Ord k => Mapping k (Map.Map k) where
  empty = Map.empty
  search = Map.lookup
  insert = Map.insert
  delete = Map.delete

data Trie m v = Trie {
  trValue :: Maybe v,
  trChildren :: m (Trie m v)
}

deriving instance (Show v, Show (m (Trie m v))) => Show (Trie m v)

trieMod :: Mapping k m => Maybe v -> [k] -> Trie m v -> Trie m v
trieMod val [] trie = trie { trValue = val }
trieMod val (x:xs) trie =
  trie { trChildren = insert x newChild children }
  where
    children = trChildren trie
    newChild = trieMod val xs prevChild
    prevChild = fromMaybe empty . search x $ children

instance Mapping k m => Mapping [k] (Trie m) where
  empty = Trie { trValue = Nothing, trChildren = empty }
  search [] trie = trValue trie
  search (x:xs) trie =
    search xs =<< search x (trChildren trie)
  insert key val = trieMod (Just val) key
  delete = trieMod Nothing

type TernarySearchTree a = Trie (Map.Map a)
```

Btw: Had functional dependencies not existed, we would probably need to compromise on an annoying interface and use function tables instead of type classes.

Comment: @Titou: Regarding your edit - see the discussion above with @GaneshSittampalam about removing `v` from the  type class definition. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1019928/haskell-type-classes-question/1020264#comment829685_1019928 http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1019928/haskell-type-classes-question/1020264#comment829844_1020134

Comment: Thanks for taking the time to point out the mistake, because it was a false belief I would not have questioned without your message.